# Date range query in SearchKick (elastic search)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have a Rails 5 app that lists a collection of events. I have SearchKick set up nicely and I am now trying to add functionality that only displays the events from today onwards but I'm struggling with the implementation. I currently have the following:

`events_controller.rb`

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

    def index
      query = params[:j].presence || "*"
      conditions = {}
      conditions[:sector_name] = params[:sector_name] if params[:sector_name].present?
      conditions[:service_name] = params[:service_name] if params[:service_name].present?
      conditions[:start_date] = params[:start_date] if params[:start_date].present?
      @events = Event.search query, where: conditions, aggs: [:sector_name, :service_name], range: {start_date: {"gte": "now/d"}}, order: {start_date: {order: "asc", unmapped_type: "long"}}, page: params[:page], per_page: 10
    end
  ...
end
```

`start_date` is of `date` type in my postgres db.

When I go to `index.html.erb` I'm still seeing events with a `start_date` before today's date.

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out.

```
def index
  query = params[:j].presence || "*"
  conditions = {start_date: {"gte": "now/d"}}
  conditions[:sector_name] = params[:sector_name] if params[:sector_name].present?
  conditions[:service_name] = params[:service_name] if params[:service_name].present?
  conditions[:start_date] = params[:start_date] if params[:start_date].present?
  @events = Event.search query, where: conditions, aggs: [:sector_name, :service_name], order: {start_date: {order: "asc", unmapped_type: "long"}}, page: params[:page], per_page: 10
end
```

I simply passed `start_date: {"gte": "now/d"}` into the conditions hash. This means it now works in conjunctions with my aggs search.

Comment: hi Billy. how do you show aggregations in index if you have any and also what do you have in your form that allows sector name and service name to be selected? thanks man